# Nautilus Scripts - Select every second file

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-actions, nautilus-script, nautilus-extensions

Is it possible to write a script to select every second file

I found something similar

http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/cat-filesysmgt.php

but it's been taken off line.

I create numerous routine backups, after a while it's no use keeping all of them, halving them by selecting every second one would be useful.

Using Nautilus 3.4 the one from Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it would be wiser to move the files to a Trash folder rather than to delete them altogether.You can achieve this by selecting script from nautilus context menu. I can't tell what script you are referring to, but this one will do just fine.

So, create the script, make it executable and place it in the nautilus script folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
comm_susbst=$(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")
files_del=$(echo "$comm_susbst" | sed -n 'n;p')
num_files=$(echo "$files_del" | wc -l)
zenity --question --title="Delete every second file" \
--text="Are you sure you want to delete these files? \n You will delete $num_files files! \n\n $files_del"
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        echo "$files_del" | while read; do mv -t /home/$USER/.local/share/Trash/files "$REPLY"; sleep 0.1; done
    else exit 1
    fi
exit 0
```

After selecting files and running a script zenity window will pop-up for confirmation.If you insist on deleting files than replace the `mv` line with `do rm -f "$REPLY"`. I hope it works as you imagine it will :)